# How to make flowchart with procedures?

Tags: pascal, freepascal, flowchart

There's to many procedures in my code
and there's too many gotoxy and write's in my code
How to make flowchart for this whole program in this situation ?

```
uses crt;
var a,b,c : integer;
user,pass : string;

procedure loading;
var titikloading: integer;
begin
        titikloading := 15;
        for a:=1 to 50 do
        begin
                gotoxy(38,15);
                write(a*2,'%');
                delay(50);
                gotoxy(titikloading,17);
                write(#177);
                titikloading:= titikloading+1;

        end;
        delay(500);

end;




procedure username;
begin
textcolor(white);
        gotoxy(27,12);
        write('Username : ');
        readln(user);
        while (user <> 'fti') do
        begin
                gotoxy(38,12);
                write('                                   ');
                username;
        end;

end;
procedure password;
begin
        textcolor(white);
        gotoxy(27,13);
        write('Password : ');
        readln(pass);
        while (pass <> 'fti') do
        begin
                gotoxy(38,13);
                write('                                 ');
                password;
        end;
end;


PROCEDURE f;
begin
gotoxy(20,7);  writeln('*****'); delay(200);
gotoxy(20,8);  writeln('*    '); delay(200);
gotoxy(20,9);  writeln('*****'); delay(200);
gotoxy(20,10); writeln('*    '); delay (200);
gotoxy(20,11); writeln('*'    ); delay (200);
end;

procedure t;
begin
gotoxy(38,3); writeln('*****'); delay(200);
gotoxy(38,4); writeln('  *'); delay(200);
gotoxy(38,5); writeln('  *'); delay(200);
gotoxy(38,6); writeln('  *'); delay(200);
gotoxy(38,7); writeln('  *'); delay(200);
end;

procedure i;
begin
gotoxy(60,7);  writeln('*'); delay(200);
gotoxy(60,8);  writeln('*'); delay(200);
gotoxy(60,9);  writeln('*'); delay(200);
gotoxy(60,10); writeln('*'); delay(200);
gotoxy(60,11); writeln('*'); delay(200);
end;

procedure u;
begin
gotoxy(15,15);writeln('*   *'); delay(200);
gotoxy(15,16);writeln('*   *'); delay(200);
gotoxy(15,17);writeln('*   *'); delay(200);
gotoxy(15,18);writeln('*   *'); delay(200);
gotoxy(15,19);writeln('*****'); delay(200);
end;

procedure k;
begin
gotoxy(30,20);writeln('*   *'); delay(200);
gotoxy(30,21);writeln('* *  '); delay(200);
gotoxy(30,22);writeln('***  '); delay(200);
gotoxy(30,23);writeln('* *  '); delay(200);
gotoxy(30,24);writeln('*   *'); delay(200);
end;

procedure s;
begin
gotoxy(50,20);writeln('*****'); delay(200);
gotoxy(50,21);writeln('*    '); delay(200);
gotoxy(50,22);writeln('*****'); delay(200);
gotoxy(50,23);writeln('    *'); delay(200);
gotoxy(50,24);writeln('*****'); delay(200);
end;

procedure w;
begin
gotoxy(65,15);writeln('*   *'); delay(200);
gotoxy(65,16);writeln('*   *');   delay(200);
gotoxy(65,17);writeln('*   *');   delay(200);
gotoxy(65,18);writeln('* * *');   delay(200);
gotoxy(65,19);writeln('** **'); delay(200);
end;
BEGIN
  clrscr;
        username;
        password;
        loading;
        clrscr;

f;t;i;u;k;s;w;

END;
```

I'm not sure if I should make each statement in one shape in flowchart, because it's weird for others to understand.

What do you think guys?

Comment: This question should probably go on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. Personally I am not sure flow charts would aid much in understanding your code, but better identifier names certainly could :)